# Could not load assembly 'monotouch'

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I get this error whenever I run my Android app created in Xamarin studio. I can't seem to find much on this, has anyone dealt with this issue and found a way to fix this? Any help is much appreciated!

```
Error: Exception while loading assemblies: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'monotouch, Version=0.0.0.0, ...
```

Comment: FWIW, I'm also running into this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The monotouch assembly is used by iOS projects. For Android projects should be using the Mono.Android assembly.

I would try remove the monotouch reference from the Android project.

Comment: I'm not actually referencing monotouch in my Android app though, I have an iOS and an Android project that references a master project in my solution. My iOS project is referencing monotouch, while my Android app is referencing Mono.Android

Comment: It looks like something is referencing monotouch. Is monotouch in the output directory of your Android project?

Comment: Shouldn't be, but I'm not a 100% sure. I'm just starting to dive into creating the android app project for my solution, so it's likely I missed a necessary step... Do you happen to have any links or advice regarding that possibility?